# catch all unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unhandled-exception

How do I catch *all* unhandled exceptions that occur in ASP.NET Web Api so that I can log them?

So far I have tried:

- Create and register an [`ExceptionHandlingAttribute`](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/11/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling.aspx)
- Implement an `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs`
- Subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
- Subscribe to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`

The `ExceptionHandlingAttribute` successfully handles exceptions that are thrown within controller action methods and action filters, but other exceptions are not handled, for example:

- Exceptions thrown when an `IQueryable` returned by an action method fails to execute
- Exceptions thrown by a message handler (i.e. `HttpConfiguration.MessageHandlers`)
- Exceptions thrown when creating a controller instance

Basically, if an exception is going to cause a 500 Internal Server Error to be returned to the client, I want it logged. Implementing `Application_Error` did this job well in Web Forms and MVC - what can I use in Web Api?

Comment: Have you tried using [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx)? Just enable it and see whether your exceptions aren't logged to the event log.

Comment: Health Monitoring catches my MVC pipeline exceptions, but not my Web Api pipeline exceptions.

Comment: Thanks - It took me a while to figure out why I couldn't log my constructor / dependency injection issues, where I thought I had WebAPI logging sorted already...

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This is now possible with WebAPI 2.1 (see the [What's New](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error)):

Create one or more implementations of IExceptionLogger. For example:

```
public class TraceExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(context.ExceptionContext.Exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then register with your application's HttpConfiguration, inside a config callback like so:

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TraceExceptionLogger());
```

or directly:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TraceExceptionLogger());
```

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Yes, Web API 2.1 corresponds to System.Web.Http assembly version **5.1.0**. So you need this version or above to use the solution described here. See [the nuget package versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.1.0)

Comment: Certain 500 errors still don't get caught by this, eg. HttpException - the remote host closed the connection.  Is there still a place for global.asax Application_Error to handle errors outside web api processing?

Comment: I love how detailed the official doco is on msdn and what 99% of developers really want is just the 8 lines of code to log errors.

Comment: I'm sure it still doesn't catch all the 500 errors: for example, if an error is thrown inside the Invoke method of a custom Owin Middleware!

Answer (score 21):

To answer my own question, this isn't possible!

Handling all exceptions that cause internal server errors seems like a basic capability Web API should have, so I have put in a request with Microsoft for a **Global error handler for Web API**:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1001

If you agree, go to that link and vote for it!

In the meantime, the excellent article [ASP.NET Web API Exception Handling](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/11/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling.aspx) shows a few different ways to catch a few different categories of error. It's more complicated than it should be, and it doesn't catch *all* interal server errors, but it's the best approach available today.

**Update:** Global error handling is now implemented and available in the nightly builds! It will be released in ASP.NET MVC v5.1. Here's how it will work: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling

Comment: seems like a reason to use controller for ajax calls instead of web api.. the boundaries are already blurry.. although if ELMAH is able to capture it, maybe there is a way

Comment: Global error handling now been added in Web API 2.1. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 21):

The Yuval's answer is for customizing responses to unhandled exceptions caught by Web API, not for logging, as noted on the linked [page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling). Refer to the When to Use section on the page for details. The logger is always called but the handler is called only when a response can be sent. In short, use the [logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382651/2028733) to log and the handler to customize the response.

By the way, I am using assembly v5.2.3 and the [`ExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/ExceptionHandler.cs) class does not have the `HandleCore` method. The equivalent, I think, is `Handle`. However, simply subclassing `ExceptionHandler` (as in Yuval's answer) does not work. In my case, I have to implement `IExceptionHandler` as follows.

```
internal class OopsExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly IExceptionHandler _innerHandler;

    public OopsExceptionHandler (IExceptionHandler innerHandler)
    {
        if (innerHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerHandler));

        _innerHandler = innerHandler;
    }

    public IExceptionHandler InnerHandler
    {
        get { return _innerHandler; }
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Handle(context);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Create your own custom result here...
        // In dev, you might want to null out the result
        // to display the YSOD.
        // context.Result = null;
        context.Result = new InternalServerErrorResult(context.Request);
    }
}
```

Note that, unlike the logger, you register your handler by replacing the default handler, not adding.

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
    new OopsExceptionHandler(config.Services.GetExceptionHandler()));
```

Comment: This is a great solution, this should be the accepted solution to 'catch or log all errors'. I could have never figured out what why it didn't work for me when I was just extending ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Great solution.  Once the MVC pipeline has been loaded for a request this works great.  IIS still handles the exceptions until then, including when spinning up OWIN in startup.cs.  However, at some point after spin up finishes processing startup.cs it does it's job wonderfully.

Answer (score 11):

You can also create a global exception handler by implementing the `IExceptionHandler` interface (or inherit the `ExceptionHandler` base class). It will be the last to be called in the execution chain, after all registered `IExceptionLogger`:

> The IExceptionHandler handles all unhandled exceptions from all
>   controllers. This is the last in the list. If an exception occurs, the
>   IExceptionLogger will be called first, then the controller
>   ExceptionFilters and if still unhandled, the IExceptionHandler
>   implementation.

```
public class OopsExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
        {
            Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong."        
        };
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

More on that [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling).

Comment: Just curious, where is this registerd?

Comment: Handler can be registered with your dependency injection framework

Answer (score -1):

You may have existing try-catch blocks that you're not aware of.

I thought my new `global.asax.Application_Error` method wasn't being consistently called for unhandled exceptions in our legacy code.

Then I found a few try-catch blocks in the middle of the call stack that called Response.Write on the Exception text. That was it. Dumped the text on the screen then killed the exception stone dead.

So the exceptions were being handled, but the handling was doing nothing useful. Once I removed those try-catch blocks the exceptions propagated to the Application_Error method as expected.