# WebAPI Global Exception Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a ASP WebAPI project. I'm trying to setup a global exception handler on my basecontroller. So I created an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` like so.

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception;
        log.Fatal(exception);

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Then I also registered it in `/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // ...

        // Setup Filters
        config.Filters.Add(new MyExceptionFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

When I add the attributes to my controller (or base-controller), nothing gets logged. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: My controller throwing the exception:**

```
[HttpGet]
public string Hello(string name)
{
    if (name.Equals("error", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
    else
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of exception you missed,there are number of case that filter fails to handle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like @ShekharPankaj had pointed out, not all exceptions are handled by the attribute (or the approach @Matías provided). My code was fine. I simple changed the exception to a `ArgumentException` and it gets handled.

See also this SO-thread: [catch all unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028919/catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api#answer-16158704)

> To answer my own question, this isn't possible!
>
> Handling all exceptions that cause internal server errors seems like a
> basic capability Web API should have, so I have put in a request with
> Microsoft for a Global error handler for Web API:
>
> https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1001
>
> If you agree, go to that link and vote for it!
>
> In the meantime, the excellent article ASP.NET Web API Exception
> Handling shows a few different ways to catch a few different
> categories of error. It's more complicated than it should be, and it
> doesn't catch all interal server errors, but it's the best approach
> available today.
>
> Update: Global error handling is now implemented and available in the
> nightly builds! It will be released in ASP.NET MVC v5.1. Here's how it
> will work:
> https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling

It looks like the links in the old Stackoverflow post are not valid anymore. The article on how to handle errors can be found [on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling).

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to update the links

Answer (score 12):

Actually when you add that filter to your `HttpConfiguration` it means that it will be executed for any action. That is, you don't need to add the whole attribute to your API controllers.

What can be skipping your filter? Other filter. The first filter to set the response wins and it can happen that the action itself gets never executed.

Anyway, maybe you need to switch to implement an `IExceptionHandler` and configure it as follows:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

This approach is better because it's a true last-chance exception handler and it will be always called independently of the behavior of filters.

Comment: I like the approach but does it also work for non-async methods? The only method I need to implement is `Task HandleAsync()`

Comment: @Thijs Yeah, it's absolutely global

Comment: Because the debugger doesn't enter the method when I throw the exception.

Comment: @Thijs Try to inherit this class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.exceptionhandling.exceptionhandler(v=vs.118).aspx and override the synchronous `Handle`...

Comment: Nope, not entering in it.

Comment: @Thijs Did you inherit that class?

Comment: Yes I did. I inherited both the class as the interface.

Comment: @Thijs No, you need to inherit the class, and don't re-implement the whole interface. Drop it in your custom exception handler

Comment: Removed the interface, didn't made a difference.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I put the question out here :).

Comment: @Thijs You should test this using a very simple sample in your own solution. I don't know how's your code at all (well you've added where you throw the exception but...)

Comment: @Thijs Follow this tutorial and check if you've done everything in the right way: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling